# Convert People Picker to New Text Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint online list where I have a People Picker field ("PeoplePickerColumn").

I want to create a new text column ("PeopleTextColumn") in the list that populates based on the "PeoplePickerColumn" value.

I'm fairly new to SharePoint and do not know JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the data in text column in list view, you can use below JSON code:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "[$PeoplePickerColumn.title]"
}
```

Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of your People Picker field in `txtContent`. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

If you want to store the actual value in text column, it is not possible with JSON formatting.

To populate the value in text column on list item creation/update, you have to call a power automate flow & perform update operation.